# Getting time out in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, java-websocket

I am trying for a webscoket connection using websocket sampler. For that for that firstly I am adding a http request for websocket server since my application internally binded with ws and externally can view with http.I am getting connection[websocker server][1\ time out while trying to connect to websocket protocol. kindly help me

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazySchemeSocketFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:654)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:413)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1166)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1155)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: too few details. Are you trying to upgrade from HTTP to websockets? how do your HTTP and websocket requests look?

Comment: http requests that do login. And open WebSocket Sampler with wss protocol. Pass token to it. It doesn't throw error. But in result i see that Cannot connect to the remote server.